# How to resolve conflicting go module dependencies when a top-level module and one of its sub-modules are separately imported as separate versions?

Tags: go, dependencies, dependency-management, go-modules

I have two dependencies in my project.

`go.mod`:

```
module github.com/test-org/test-repo

go 1.12

require (
    github.com/foo/bar v1.0.0
    github.com/raz/mataz v1.0.0
)
```

---

After running `go mod download`, those two dependencies result in two different versions of a `github.com/shared/dependency` to be downloaded. The interesting thing is that the `github.com/shared/dependency` contains sub-modules, e.g.:

```
dependency
  -- go.mod
  -- api
      -- go.mod
```

Inspecting the downloaded modules shows two versions are downloaded to my local machine:

`ls ${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared`:

```
[dir] dependency    [dir] dependency@v1.1.0
```

`ls ${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared/dependency`:

```
[dir] api@v1.2.0
```

---

Looking at the contents of these directories:

`${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared/dependency@v1.1.0`:

The file contents of the whole repo in v1.1.0, including the `api` folder with its own `go.mod` file.

`${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared/dependency/api@v1.2.0`:

The file contents of the `api` folder of the repo in v1.2.0, including the `go.mod` file.

---

Finally, I have a `.go` file in my `test-repo` with the following setup:

```
package test-package

import (
    "github.com/foo/bar"
)

func MyFunc() {...bar.NewBar()...}
```

When I try to run a test of `MyFunc` (that exists elsewhere), I get an `unknown import path...ambiguous import...` error message. e.g.

`go test github.com/test-org/test-repo/test-package -test.run=TestMyFunc -v`:

```
unknown import path "github.com/shared/dependency/api": ambiguous import: found github.com/shared/dependency/api in multiple modules:
    github.com/shared/dependency v1.1.0 (${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared/dependency@v1.1.0/api)
    github.com/shared/dependency v1.2.0 (${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared/dependency/api@v1.2.0)
```

The error points to the `import` line of the `.go` file importing `github.com/shared/dependency/api` in the `github.com/foo/bar` repo. It doesn't know which `api` to choose in my local `${GOPATH}/pkg/mod` folder, given the two versions available:

1. `${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared/dependency@v1.1.0/api`
2. `${GOPATH}/pkg/mod/github.com/shared/dependency/api@v1.2.0`

---

Is there any way that I can make that `go test` call work (solve the dependency conflicts)? Neither of my two dependencies explicitly call out downloading the full `shared/dependency@v1.1.0`, but for some reason it gets pulled in. If that weren't there, it would seemingly fix the issue.

Comment: Packages with major version > 1 must be imported with an import path ending in "/v2". You **cannot** have the same package (identified by its import path) in two different versions. That's why a different version needs a different import path: Append v2. Consolt the Go Modules wiki which explains all this. (Possible duplicate).

Comment: The Go modules concept builds on that modules must be semantically versioned according to semver. And if one of your requirement is `v1.12` and other is `v1.0`, that is the same major version, thus the `v1.12` must be compatible with `v1.0`, and so the go tool will choose `v1.12` which should work. If you need a different major versions, starting with `v2` it must be part of the import path, thus it will count as a different package / dependency, and all different major version will be included separately.

Comment: @Volker, I've changed the versioning in the question, as my issue isn't actually with `v1` vs. `v2`, but with `v0` vs. `v1`. So your suggestion doesn't apply. I was unaware of the `v2`+ specifics you mentioned, though. Good to know.

Comment: You _cannot_ have v0.0.0 and v1.0.0 of the same package. Dead simple. v0.0.0 is not even valid but just used for compatibility. Sometimes all you can do is fix upstream.

Comment: @Volker Ok, so if one of my dependencies requires a `v0.x.x` version of the package, and the other dependency requires a `v1.x.x` version, the only solution is to change the requirement that one of those dependencies has in its `go.mod` file? Is that correct? Initially with the go modules thing, I had the impression that sub-modules might be able to get away with different versions. For example, if I made a second `go.mod` file in my repo for my package that needed the other version of the dependency, I thought that might work, but I could be way off course with what go modules are capable of.

Comment: @icza An interesting thing is that I'm actually dealing with two errors of the same format described in the question. One is with a `v0.x.x` vs. `v1.x.x`, but the other is with a `v1.4.x` vs. a `v1.1.x`. Thus, the expected go tool behavior of automatically selecting doesn't appear to be working in this case. Note that this might be an edge case, as it involves importing a sub-module for one of those two versions (`v1.4.x` and `v1.1.x`).

Comment: To again remove the possibility of people coming to solutions to my question that do not fix the errors, I am going to change the versioning in the question to be only differences in minor versioning.

Comment: Well, semantically a module _cannot_ require v0.x.y of a dependency as this means something like "I need the dependency in a not-released version. Go goes strictly Semver here (see https://semver.org/#spec-item-4). If you really are forced to do this: Ask on golang-nuts.

Comment: Go modules resolves version according to minimum version selection. If A has transitive dependencies on B in version 1.2 and 1.4 Then version 1.4 will be chosen and you will not see an error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue turned out to be that one of the dependencies was referencing a version of the `github.com/shared/dependency/api` that was **pre-go-modules**.

This caused the go tooling to have a module reference to the `github.com/shared/dependency/api` sub-module, but also a black box import of the entire `github.com/shared/dependency` repo for the pre-go-modules version. In this example, it would mean that `v1.2.0` had go modules (had a `go.mod` file), and `v1.1.0` did not.

Adding the following line to my `go.mod` file was able to fix the issue, and this solution worked with multiple dependencies I had with such conflicts:

```
replace (
    github.com/shared/dependency => github.com/shared/dependency v1.2.0
)
```

Note that this solution only works because we are forcing references to the shared dependency to use go-module-enabled versions (v1.2.0+).

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I found that running `go get github.com/shared/dependency/api@latest` seemed to work when the `replace` method above did not.

Presumably this is forcing both modules to use the latest version of the dependency.

Answer (score -1):

### I Simply solved issues of `ambiguous import: found package time in multiple modules:`

Just **delete** the `mod` file and `go mod init` again with some different name that **not** matches with any **existing** module name.

`go mod init time` - **INCORRECT**

`go mod init gotime` - **CORRECT**